# Navigate from a ViewController to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

I made a storyboard game. I set 3 lives and now i want when all the lives age gone to call another viewcontroller, like results viewcontroller to sow the score results. How am i supposed to do that? to call the other controller?

Comment: Have you read any documentation about segues?

Comment: yes i know how to move from one to another with moddal but with buttons not with the if statment for example when the lives are 0 open the results controller. thats my question.thank you

Comment: You should update you question with your last comment as it's bit clearer, also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992716/navigate-to-another-viewcontroller-programmatically-using-custom-segue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to Load your View controller:

```
YourViewController *controller = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifire"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```